# Return unique rows based on minimum id in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've stuck on this:
I need get **guid** based on minimum **ID** and remove all other duplicates (guid, ID).
ID is only unique field here.

```
+-----------------------------+------+-------------+
| guid                        | ID   | post_parent |
+-----------------------------+------+-------------+
| 5.jpg                       | 7626 |        2418 |
| 3.jpg                       | 7625 |        2418 |
| 2.jpg                       | 5972 |        2418 |
| 2.jpg                       | 3000 |        2420 |
| 0.jpg                       | 3205 |        2420 |
| 9.jpg                       | 9205 |        2419 |
+-----------------------------+------+-------------+
```

So what I want:

```
+-----------------------------+------+-------------+
| guid                        | ID   | post_parent |
+-----------------------------+------+-------------+
| 2.jpg                       | 5972 |        2418 |
| 2.jpg                       | 3000 |        2420 |
| 9.jpg                       | 9205 |        2419 |
+-----------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Sure, I may use something like this:

```
select guid,
       ID 
       from wp_posts where ID = ( 
        select MIN(ID) from wp_posts 
        where post_parent="2418");
```

But I need to get all data from table, not single rows.

Comment: Query from @user1717259 query works like a charm :)
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
  from wp_posts p,
       (select min(ID) as id, post_parent
          from wp_posts 
      group by post_parent) mins
  where p.ID = mins.id and mins.post_parent = p.post_parent
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the row with the minimum id

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 'a'
                    FROM wp_posts p2
                    WHERE p2.post_parent = p.post_parent 
                    AND p2.id < p.id
                  )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct z.guid, z.id, z.post_parent from (
    select distinct post_parent, min(id) pp 
    from wp_posts
    group by post_parent
) bb
inner join wp_posts z on z.post_parent = bb.post_parent and z.id = bb.pp
```